# Dictionary not assigning value to variable

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign a value from a dictionary to a variable but the variable remains unchanged. The value is another dictionary.

The code I used to generate the dictionaries can be found here: http://pastebin.com/Q2Hc8Ktp

I wrote it myself and tested it without this problem.

Here is the code snipit of me trying to copy the dictionary from the dictionary.

```
_classes = {}

def populateClasses():
    print "Classes Exist"
    cp = Preferences(''.join([resource_path,"resources.ini"]))
    print cp
    _classes = cp.getPreferences()['Classes']

populateClasses()
print _classes
```

When I print out cp it shows the correct data but when I try to print _classes it only shows {}

Note: printing _classes from within the function works as expected but not from outside the function. _classes is defined in the global scope

-Edit-

Here is also some sample data:

```
[Classes]
Wizard = Arcana, Bluff
Warrior = Endurance, Intimidate
Ranger = Nature, Perception
Bard = Heal, History
```

Comment: use `global _classes = {}

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the value of the global variable `_classes`, you need to use [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt):

```
def populateClasses():
    global _classes   # <<<<<< THIS
    print "Classes Exist"
    cp = Preferences(''.join([resource_path,"resources.ini"]))
    print cp
    _classes = cp.getPreferences()['Classes']
```

Without this, your method creates a separate local variable also called `_classes`. This variable goes out of scope as soon as your method returns.

Comment: It fixed my problem. In another function I assigned lists to two variables without declaring global in the function without issue. Not sure what the difference was.

Comment: It might have been I was using the append method on the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `global`, you might use `_classes.update(cp.getPreferences()['Classes'])`.

The rule for globals is that you need the `global` keyword if you write to it, but don't need it if you're just accessing the variable (even if that access is mutating the state). That's why my suggestion above doesn't need a `global` statement, and the original code does. Possibly that's also what happened when you "assigned lists to two variables" and didn't need `global`.